# Accessing of the scope variable from one .js to another .js in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm completely new to node.js. I need to send the data from `upload.js` > `path.js`. I tried using `exports`, It didn't work. How can I achieve this, any leads?
In the below file `upload.js` i have the file name stored in `myFile`.

```
app.post('/testUpload', upload.single('file'), function(req,res,) {
    debug(req.file);
    var myFile = req.file.filename
     console.log(myFile);// need to send this value into path.js
    exports.myFile= myFile;
    return res.send(req.file);
})
```

I want to send this `myFile` value to `path.js`. I tried using `export`it didn't work. Below is the code

```
var fileupload = require("./fileupload");
myFile = fileupload.myFile;
conn.on('ready', function (myFile) {
    console.log(" I want my file Inside here " + myFile);// need variable data here
    conn.sftp(function (err, sftp) {
      //  if (err) throw err;

        var fs = require("fs"); // Use node filesystem

        var readStream = fs.createReadStream("/xyz/" + myFile);// need variable data here
        var writeStream = sftp.createWriteStream("/xvy/" + myFile);// need variable data here
        writeStream.on('close', function () {
            console.log("- file transferred succesfully");
        });

        writeStream.on('end', function () {
            console.log("sftp connection closed");
            conn.close();
        });

        // initiate transfer of file
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    });
}).connect(connSettings);
```

Comment: Did you get some errors in console or it just show nothing?

Comment: @Schwarz54 In the `path.js` i'm getting undefined

Comment: Can you brief what you want to achieve? I guess you like to upload a file for route app.post('/testUpload'). If so some questions I like to ask: 
When do you want to return the response? (After file upload or before file upload)
When path.js will be called?

Comment: @jerry I want to store the file name in `upload.js` and want to use that file name in my other file. Response after uploading the file(.ie file name in upload .js)

Comment: @SaiManoj Okay, so you want to return the response as soon as you have the filename. In the process when path.js will be called?

Comment: Got it. Thanks..

Comment: you can use an event emitter with arguments https://nodejs.org/api/events.html